# Do we need to use spoiler tags on Futurama questions?

Tags: discussion, spoilers, futurama

On my question here: [How did Senator Travers not just survive as a Time Paradox Duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19301/3383) someone added some spoiler tags and I reverted them.

Do we **need** to have spoiler tags on things that are soon to become common knowledge? (Especially if you watch [futurama](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/futurama)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I should point out that I only added the spoiler tags since in the body of your question itself you state "(stop reading if you do not want spoilers)". I figured (incorrectly apparently) that you were simply unaware of the fact that there is a specific way to hide spoilers within a question, since you clearly were indicating to users that the next area of the question contained spoilers.

I think that since they are available, they should be used when it is reasonable to assume that the majority of people reading the question will be unaware of the spoiler. That being said, in this case since understanding the title of the question itself indicates knowledge of the episode itself, the tags are probably *unnecessarily redundant* and *superfluous.*

Comment: Exactly :-) `+1`

Answer (score 2):

I think for that question, which is about last night's episode, spoiler tagging things is considerate.  However, since the question title itself is a spoiler, it seems a bit pointless to have the body text in spoiler tags.

Personally, it'd be nice if the question title was made generic enough to not be a spoiler, and spoiler tags employed in the question body.  But I acknowledge that I'm pretty pro-spoiler tag in general.

Comment: Hmmm ok. Could u delete all the spam answers that seemed to have cropped up on that question?